# CsvHelper: writing null strings as special string

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm trying to configure CsvWriter to use special string "#NULL#" for nullable string properties. For reader it works, by setting `csvReader.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<string>().NullValues.Add("#NULL#");`  - it reads "#NULL#" fields in csv as null strings.

The code I'm using for writer is below, but it ignores added NullValues and outputs empty strings instead (default behavior). 
Is there other config parameter for writer? Thanks.

```
        public class Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void csv_write_test()
    {
        var entities = new[] {new Entity {Id = 1, Name = null}, new Entity {Id=2, Name = "SampleName"} };

        var fileName = "C:/Temp/tr/recordings/withNulls/sample-test.csv";
        File.Delete(fileName);

        using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(textWriter);

            csvWriter.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<string>().NullValues.Add("#NULL#");

            csvWriter.WriteRecords(entities);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try setting [IWriterConfiguration](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/IWriterConfiguration.cs)`.UseNewObjectForNullReferenceMembers = true;`  If I read the doku correct the `NullValues` might only work for reading though, so that value will be converted to null if read. Not sure if the same applies on writing and not sure which one is used if multiple are taken.

Comment: @PatrickArtner It didn't change output, and it is actually true by default.

Comment: I think it's not possible without some heavy reflection. Library is just not designed for this. I'd suggest to open an issue on their tracker and ask to add this feature.

Comment: @Evk It is working on deserialization (reader) level though. I'd expect the same on serialization level, as writer is using the same configuration object.

Comment: There might be multiple values in NullValues collection, which one to use? Anyway, it just doesn't work like this right now.

Comment: @Evk That's a fair point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom `ITypeConverter` to accomplish this.

```
void Main()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
    {
        var records = new List<Test>
        {
            new Test { Id = 1, Name = "one" },
            new Test { Id = 2, Name = null },
        };

        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TestMap>();
        csv.WriteRecords(records);

        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        reader.ReadToEnd().Dump();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public sealed class TestMap : ClassMap<Test>
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Name).TypeConverter<CustomNullTypeConverter<string>>();
    }
}

public class CustomNullTypeConverter<T> : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return "#NULL#";
        }

        var converter = row.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.GetConverter<T>();
        return converter.ConvertToString(value, row, memberMapData);
    }
}
```

If you want it to use the first value in the `NullValues` option, you'll need to submit a feature request.

Comment: did a PR ever get raised for this? If not, I'd happily add it?